# Is there an accepted Angular 2 ecosystem yet?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, build

I'm an Angular 1 dev currently looking to get to grips with Angular 2, however with the changes and rewrites so far it's a bit of a quagmire.

All of the full ecosystems I've found are from late 2015, the testing ngdocs are outdated and there doesn't seem to be a clear up to date scaffold for Angular 2.

Has anyone come across a recommended setup or been able to set something up themselves? Something like Yeo is not strictly necessary but I'd need Typescript compilation and linting, live reload for development, unit testing, minification, SASS compilation and dependency management.

I would default to Gulp, Jasmine & Karma for the build system and tests but ideally I want to start off learning the best suited technologies from the start.

Bonus points for Webstorm integration :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check out the [Angular-CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) project. It's an official CLI toolchain with testing and build built in. It's still a bit unstable with the changeover to webpack, but if you're working with RC software that's to be expected.

Comment: Looks like exactly the place to start, thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for `angular-cli` to become a bit more mature, I've been using the [Fountain Webapp](https://github.com/FountainJS/generator-fountain-webapp) generator. Long term, I'll probably move to `angular-cli`.